What is the original source of the quote "Of all my 50 battles, the most terrible was the one I fought at Moscow"?
And how does the quote look in French? The reason I ask is that I see this quote attributed to Napoleon cited all over the Internet (e.g. this video on the Battle of Borodino), but nobody seems to provide the source, and I can't find the quote in French (admittedly, I am not very competent French speaker). A while ago I've also seen a claim that Napoleon originally said "of all the battles I won, the most terrible was...", but the author of the claim didn't provide the source either.

The Fondation Napoleon gives a slightly longer quote: "Of the fifty battles I have fought, the most terrible was that before Moscow. The French showed themselves to be worthy victors, and the Russians can rightly call themselves invincible." This led me to On This Day, who say that Bonaparte wrote a similar quote "in his diary". Maybe somebody with better access to the source material and more time at hand can take it from there.

Strangely, the earliest French versions I can find are by Russian/Soviet authors and date to the 1950s and 1960s. Example: "De toutes mes batailles, la plus terrible a été celle que j'ai donnée devant Moscou", disait Napoléon peu avant sa mort - "les Français s'y étaient montrés dignes de remporter la victoire et les Russes dignes de rester invincibles" This leads me to believe that this is a made-up quotation, or based on a original that used significantly different wording.

Yes, I, too, suspect the quotation to be made-up. However, it would be nice to prove or disprove this definitively. Is there a digitalized version of Napoleon's diaries in question?

@DaigakunoBaku 40K+ letters of N. Bonaparte's correspondence are extant. You could try searching it at the archive of the Fondation Napoleon. I consulted a printed collection of Napoleon's writings on war from his time on St. Helena (since he supposedly made this remark late in life) but did not make a note of the name of the publication. The section on the war in Russia did not contain anything resembling the quote from the question.

@DaigakunoBaku Google Books offers scans of volumes from Correspondance de Napoléon Ier, published on the order of Napoleon III at Imprimerie Impériale in Paris between 1860 and 1870 or so. This collection ran to at least 30 volumes. To the best of my knowledge, Napoleon did not actually keep a diary.

@DaigakunoBaku Napoleon's remarks on the "Bataille de la Moskova" (Battle of Borodino) are in volume 31 of the Correspondance. This is the reference I mentioned earlier.
